# Puppetteer Selects using Xpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xpath, puppeteer

I am trying to select an option dynamically using puppeteer but I'm running into some problems on how to get it correctly. I need to get the actual `value` associated with the `option` tag. This is making my problem a bit harder. I searched a little bit and found that some people are using Xpath to make the problem a little easier to get, but it seems that my Xpath is not working correctly, as I'm getting an error ->

> The string '//select[@id = "wrestler"]/option[text() = Henri Mugnier]' is not a valid XPath expression.

`Henri Mugnier` is at index 0 in my `holderArr` array.

Here is my small code snippet.

```js
const option = (await frame.$x(
    `//select[@id = "wrestler"]/option[text() = ${holderArr[i].name}]`
))[0];
```

`holderArr` is getting passed in from another function, it's an array of objects. The dropdown is a list of names, but the `value` for each of them is just random numbers, So I'm hoping that using an xpath and then grabbing the value with a function like this

```js
const value = await (await option.getProperty('value')).jsonValue();
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://www.trackwrestling.com/seasons/
2. 2021-22 High School Boys > select 'Tennessee Secondary School Athletic Association'
3. Click 'Team' at the top
4. Select any team
5. Select 'Matches' or More
6. Select Matches (This dropdown is the one I'm trying to access)

Comment: Please show the site or markup you're working with. See [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to get an element's value, use `evaluate()` and return the value.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I ended up getting it to work. This will give you the `value` property on the `option` tag using puppeteer.

```
 let [optElementHandle] = await frame.$x(`//select[@id="wrestler"]//option[contains(text() , "${holderArr[i].name}")]`)
    const text = await optElementHandle.getProperty('value')
    const value = await text.jsonValue()
```